# Sharing Memory Mapped File Structure between c++ and c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have 2 applications, 1 is C++ and one is C# made. The following is my structure inside C++:

```
struct INFO
{
    char Name[MAX_PATH];
    int Number;
};
```

The following is my attempt to replicate the structure in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct INFO
{
   public byte Name;
   public int Number;
}
```

**The C++ Program ( ready to compile and test ):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP

// System Include
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

struct INFO
{
    char Name[MAX_PATH];
    int Number;
};

HANDLE FileMappingHandle;
INFO* FileMapping;

void EntryProc()
{
    if ((FileMappingHandle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(INFO), "Local\\INFO_MAPPING")) == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((FileMapping = (INFO*)MapViewOfFile(FileMappingHandle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(INFO))) == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    strcpy(FileMapping->Name, "DARKVADER");

    FileMapping->Number = 1337;

    printf("FileMapping->Name: %s", FileMapping->Name);
    printf("FileMapping->Number: %d", FileMapping->Number);
}


int main()
{
    EntryProc();
    do {
        cout << '\n' << "Press the Enter key to continue.";
    } while (cin.get() != '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

**The C# Program ( ready to compile and test ):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoMap();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct INFO
        {
            public byte Name;
            public int Number;
        }

        public void DoMap()
        {
            MemoryMappedFileSecurity CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
            CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

            //access memory mapped file (need persistence)
            using (var memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Local\\INFO_MAPPING", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, CustomSecurity, System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
            {
                using (var accessor = memMapFile.CreateViewAccessor())
                {
                    INFO data;

                    accessor.Read<INFO>(0, out data);

                    Console.WriteLine(data.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.Number);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

I can share numbers between the two applications using the above code, but I cannot share strings.

When I say "cannot" share, what I actually means is that instead of the actual "characters" I always get wierd chinese symbols, and even the number dissapears.

I have tried all the combinations I could think of ( byte[], string, unsafe struct, etc), in the C# struct but I have failed.

Please show me / explain to me how can I share properly strings between my 2 applications.

Example working code would be appreciated.

Comment: Well the current attempt contains `public byte Name;` which is a *single* byte, so this definitely can't work. A `byte[MAX_PATH]` should work; maybe there's some "magic" you could apply with attributes, if not, you can always convert the byte array to a string using `Encoding.GetString()`.

Comment: You are correct, but I have ran out of options... you know how it is when you desperately search for a solution for 7+ hours and you end up with nothing ^_^. Please provide me with your expert solution...

Comment: Too much work to recreate this, so I can't write an *answer* -- the issue probably is that your struct contains a C string in the current 8bit encoding and a .NET `string` has a different internal representation (UTF-16). Just declare the member as `byte[MAX_PATH]` and write `Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(data.Name))`.

Comment: Shared memory is a very low-level way to implement process interop.  You are skipping everything you need to make it work correctly, you always have to add synchronization so you can be sure that you only try to read when the other process has written the data.  And sure, strings are not simple, variable length data is never simple.  Just don't do this at all, use a named pipe instead and you'll have much better odds for getting it correct.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well I did not think it would be so much work since I posted ready-to-use code... anyway, thanks but I have tried already what you are saying and the result is the same.

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate the information, but I have chosen this method for a reason, and I would like to use it. If an answer to my question is not possible, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To share strings you need to map them properly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings

Probably, you need to decorate (`ByValTStr` uses `CharSet` from your `StructLayout`, so it's ANSI):

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
string Name;
```

**EDIT:**
Checked on .net core. It's not allowed to use reference types in Accessor. The easiest option would be reading the array and extracting values.

```
var buffer = new byte[264];
accessor.ReadArray(0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var endIndex = Array.FindIndex(buffer, 0, 260, x => x == 0);
var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, endIndex == -1 ? 260 : endIndex);
var number = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 260);
```

**Another one is using unsafe:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct INFO
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte Name[260];
    [FieldOffset(260)]
    public int Number;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

        //access memory mapped file (need persistence)
        using (var memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(
            "Local\\INFO_MAPPING",
            1024,
            MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute,
            MemoryMappedFileOptions.None,
            System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
        {
            using (var accessor = memMapFile.CreateViewAccessor())
            {
                accessor.Read<INFO>(0, out INFO data);
                string name;
                unsafe
                {
                    name = new String((sbyte*)data.Name, 0, 260);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine(data.Number);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you read my question, I have already tried "everything" including this and the result is the same...

Comment: I don't actually see that you've tried `MarshalAsAttribute` in the question, only 'everything' which... is rather confusing

Comment: I am trying to test the code, but there is some typo I believe :/

Comment: I cannot believe that simple cast did it, I have tried before with unsafe and I failed... Thank you for your solution :) All I have to do now is implement chained structures ...